# Why does this return a " Typeerror: __init__() got a unexpected keyword argument "comment_num" " when run

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
class Blog(object):
    def __init__(self, author, description, author_id, _id=None):
        self.author = author
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.description = description
        self._id = uuid.uuid4().hex if _id is None else _id
        self.comment_num = Database.count('posts', {'blog_id': _id})
```

This is the Blog object. When I run the Flask Application it returns the error. saying it is an internal server error. What could be the cause? self.comment_num is supposed to return the number of posts the Blog has based on the Blog id from the collection posts.

JSON code

```
def json(self):
    return {
        'author': self.author,
        'author_id': self.author_id,
        'description': self.description,
        'comment_num': self.comment_num,
        '_id': self._id
    }
```

DATABASE CODE

```
@staticmethod
def count(collection, query):
    Database.DATABASE[collection].count(query)
```

I have currently deployed the application to heroku and the logs show:

[image]

If there is another more efficient way to merely display a the number of posts that a blog has by finding it in the database by blog id, please help me to use that solution.
Thank You

Comment: Could you post the entire traceback that your getting.

Comment: Your error is not about `comment_num` but `commentnum`. It's not in the code you shown to us. Looks like you're trying to build an object, giving it a unexpected `commentsnum`, but we can't guess what it its.